# Angular provider accepts function which needs dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-providers

Wasn't sure what title to give this one but basically I have an authorization provider which I have created myself which need to be configured during the config phase to have a requireLogin() function which will be run at a later date. Like this...

```
// Configure $auth service
app.config(function ($authProvider, appConfig) {

    $authProvider.setRequireLoginFunction(function($modal){

        // Use the modal service

    });
})
```

And this is the provider code

```
app.provider('$auth', function(){

    var _requireLoginFn;


    return({
        setRequireLoginFunction: setRequireLoginFunction,
        $get: instantiateAuth
    });


    function setRequireLoginFunction(fn){
        _requireLoginFn = fn;
    }


    function instantiateAuth($http, $q) {

        return({
            requireLogin: requireLogin
        });

        function requireLogin() {
            return _requireLoginFn.apply(undefined, arguments);
        }

    }

});
```

Sidenote: I'm using ng-annotate so don't use the array syntax of DI.

Anyway, as you can see, the function that is being stored in the config phase which will later be called using $auth.requireLogin.then(...) etc. needs access to the angular-ui modal service, but when I call the function later from inside the provider obviously the DI stuff isn't happening because all I've done is put $modal in the arguments of my function which isn't magic. I also can't put $modal in the dependencies of my provider because it's too early to do that, also my provider doesn't know what dependencies the function I pass in will need.

I feel the answer is probably to:

A) use the injector within the function I'm passing in to get access to $modal service or

B) Somehow run the function from inside the provider when called externally and somehow get all the supplied dependencies injected at runtime?

Sorry if I'm not able to explain this easily. I tried to make a JSfiddle but couldn't hack the code down easily.

Comment: `function instantiateAuth($http, $q, $modal)` - Why should `$modal` be handled differently?

Comment: instantiateAuth is the "$get" part that is returned, not part of the constructor. I can't put $modal in there though because the provider doesn't know what dependencies will be needed by the function that is stored during the config phase.

Comment: `instantiateAuth` is the injectable factory function. You did not mention that the dependencies (rather arguments) are variable. I'm also confused by the statement _"when called externally"_.

Comment: Sorry, I simply mean that $auth.requireLogin() will be called from elsewhere in my app (from controllers etc.) and when that happens I need it to run the function I saved earlier using $authProvider.setRequireLoginFunction() , which may (or may not) use dependencies like $modal.